# Ошибка в подключении к mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть бот, пользовалось 15 человек одновременно, все было нормально, но недавно стало появляться предупреждение:

> **PHP Warning**: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local
>   MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'

Пробовал разные решения (точнее одно, потому что перезагрузить mysql не получается через консоль), не помогает.
Пробовал вместо localhost ставить 127.0.0.1
Еще писал в поддержку хостинга, мне сказали что они проверили и все работает нормально, ошибок быть не должно.

Вот подключение :

```
$connect = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
```

Все данные указанны верно, подключался через putty, ошибок не было тоже. Соединение с БД закрывается после выполнения кода.

Comment: Предупреждение появляется постоянно или иногда?

Comment: Предупреждение иногда появляется

Comment: Места на диске достаточно? Что-нибудь внятное в логе ошибок mysql есть? Число одновременных соединений у mysql достаточно большое?

Comment: На диске свободного места более 2гб, в логе ошибок появляется только:
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/jmxrgbjy/public_html/bot/config.php on line 17

17 строка - как раз подключение.

Comment: Это сообщение из лога ошибок PHP. В логе ошибок Mysql есть что-нибудь?

Comment: Хм, простите, не подскажите где можно его найти.

Comment: В файле конфига mysql - у меня /etc/mysql/my.cnf  строчка log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log   или что-то похожее

Comment: Тогда это проблема, я не могу просмотреть папку mysql, доступ запрещен. Может есть еще способ?

Comment: а mysql сервер вам принадлежит? у вас vps? если сервер общий может банально перезагружают mysql сервер и тогда он недоступен.

Comment: Нет, не VPS, просто хостинг для сайта. Принадлежит вроде как мне, а может и нет потому что находиться в директории home/var/.. а доступ есть только к home/%username%/.. но через SSH я могу зайти в директорию где находиться папка с mysql но к самой папке доступа нет.

Comment: Похоже проблема не на вашей стороне. Иначе бы всегда были проблемы с соединением. Видимо mysql сервер для всех иногда не справляется с нагрузкой. Может есть лимит соединений к бд от одного пользователя хостинга, может что еще. возможно вы выросли по нагрузке из простого хостинга.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое за то что помогли)